# Why Socket does not throw error when unaccepted socket send a message?

Tags: java, sockets, junit, serversocket

My goal is to create a server-client that accepts 1 connection and then the server exit with code 0.

My expected result: 2nd client should fail to send message because `ServerSocket` either is closed or it does not accept the 2nd client with `serverSocket.accept()`.

My actual result: 2nd client can send message without throwing error of `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect`

My actual result `EXTRA`: If you create the 2nd client on different method, it will fail.

java/framework/Client.java

```
package framework;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Client {
  private final Socket socket;

  public Client() throws IOException {
    socket = new Socket("localhost", 80);
  }

  public void send(String message) throws IOException {
    socket.getOutputStream().write(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
  }
}
```

java/framework/Server.java

```
package framework;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Server implements Runnable {
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Server.class);

  private final ServerSocket serverSocket;

  public Server() throws IOException {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(80);
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    try (serverSocket) {
      logger.debug("Sever socket started at port " + serverSocket.getLocalPort());

      final Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
      logger.debug("Socket accepted: " + socket.getInetAddress());

      final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
      final String line = reader.readLine();
      logger.debug("Input received: " + line);

    } catch (IOException e) {
      logger.warn("something went wrong" + e);
    }

    logger.debug("Server Socket closed.");
  }
}
```

test/java/ServerClientTest.java

```
import framework.Client;
import framework.Server;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ServerClientTest {
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServerClientTest.class);

  @BeforeAll
  static void if_server_can_start_then_success() {
    logger.debug("beforeAll");
    try {
      Server server = new Server();
      Thread thread = new Thread(server);
      thread.start();
    } catch (IOException ignored) {
      Assertions.fail("failed to start the server");
    }
  }

  @Test
  void if_1st_client_can_send_message_to_server_then_success() {
    try {
      Client client = new Client();
      client.send("Hello from 1st client\r\n");

      Client client1 = new Client();
      client1.send("Hello from 2nd client\r\n");
    } catch (IOException e) {
      Assertions.fail("1st client unable to send message to server. " + e);
    }
  }
}
```

Edit:

1. do `logger.debug("Socket: " + socket.getInputStream())` inside the Client class `send` method, magically, the socket will throw `java.net.SocketException. Connection reset by peer: socket write error`. While, calling `socket.isConnected()` will return true. Yes, I know, weird to call `getInputStream` and log it, but it makes the test works as expected.

Log of original code:

```
23:37:02.418 [main] DEBUG ServerClientTest - beforeAll
23:37:02.442 [Thread-0] DEBUG framework.Server - Sever socket started at port 80

23:37:02.491 [Thread-0] DEBUG framework.Server - Socket accepted: /127.0.0.1
23:37:02.492 [Thread-0] DEBUG framework.Server - Input received: Hello from 1st client
23:37:02.493 [Thread-0] DEBUG framework.Server - Server Socket closed.


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Log of calling `socket.getInputStream()` in the Client class `send` method.

```
23:39:48.098 [main] DEBUG ServerClientTest - beforeAll

23:39:48.153 [Thread-0] DEBUG framework.Server - Sever socket started at port 80
23:39:48.188 [Thread-0] DEBUG framework.Server - Socket accepted: /127.0.0.1
23:39:48.188 [main] DEBUG framework.Client - Socket: java.net.SocketInputStream@6bf0219d
23:39:48.190 [Thread-0] DEBUG framework.Server - Input received: Hello from 1st client
23:39:48.191 [main] DEBUG framework.Client - Socket: java.net.SocketInputStream@36d585c
23:39:48.191 [Thread-0] DEBUG framework.Server - Server Socket closed.


org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: clients failed to send message.

    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:43)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail(Assertions.java:129)
    at ServerClientTest.if_clients_can_send_message_to_server_then_success(ServerClientTest.java:35)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:110)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:138)
    at framework.Client.send(Client.java:20)
    at ServerClientTest.if_clients_can_send_message_to_server_then_success(ServerClientTest.java:33)
    ... 65 more



Process finished with exit code -1
```

Comment: Why not 1) specify 1 for the backlog parameter, i.e. `serverSocket = new ServerSocket(80, 1);`, and 2) close the server socket after the first `accept()` call?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk 1) i tried to put the backlog to 1 as you said, it does nothing 2) the `try-with-resources` will close it immediately, checking with `isClosed()` return true as well. , `closing` the server after accept would kill the test I am looking to understand. @user16320675 bring a good point to discuss.

Comment: @user16320675 could you clarify what do you mean by `standard options`?

Comment: @user16320675 do you mean `backlog` from the `ServerSocket`? I tried to use backlog and set it to 1. I could not find backlog from the `Socket`.

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/ServerSocket.html#%3Cinit%3E(int,int)) do hint that the `backlog` parameter is a suggestion rather than a hard limit. I am surprised the second connection succeeds after the server socket is closed. I would still close the server socket immediately after the accept.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I double check to be sure, putting `socket.close()` after `serverSocket.accept()` will not throw error for the 2nd client.

Comment: @user16320675 do you mean you put a `Thread.sleep(1000)` before calling `accept()` or you don't put the `accept()` code altogether. I tried to remove the `accept()` code and it throws `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect` for the 1st client. Windows 10, Java 11, with `backlog = 1`. TL:DR, forget this. otherwise the topic will be too out of scope. i will provide the log for the original code.

Comment: @user16320675 I am assuming there will be breaking changes for application that migrate from Java 11 to Java 16 that use `ServerSocket` due to this statement `((no accept called so far))`. Noted, in Java 11, if ServerSocket does not have `accept`, the 1st/2nd client will throw error.

Comment: @user16320675 in this case I use `try (serverSocket) { } catch (Exception e) {}`, if there is no `serverSocket.accept()` present, it will throw `Connection refused: connect` in Windows 10, Java 11. Putting a deliberate `Thread.sleep(1000)` or `for loop` inside the bracket will do nothing. So, I think there is a bug in how `serversocket queue` and `accept()` works?

Comment: @user16320675 putting `Thread.sleep(5)` between creating `Socket` / `new Client()` does the job, it will throw `Connection refused: connect`, this is against the original code. I strongnly believe this is a `ServerSocket` issue.

Comment: @user16320675 for now I will put a comment `Thread.sleep(7); // FIXME: The server still accepts socket with X factor before 7ms.`, I will investigate how `serverSocket.accept()` and why `socket.isConnected()` return true for the 2nd client although the sevrer did not `accept()` it.

Comment: @user16320675 I converted the test to plain POJO with main method. Confirmed: multi-threading and testing framework problem. We can close this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your Client creation. There is no delay in between the creation of the two clients which causes the exclusion the connect error. Adding a delay will always result in connect error.

```
static void if_1st_client_can_send_message_to_server_then_success() {
    try {
        Client client = new Client();
        client.send("Hello from 1st client\r\n");

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        Client client1 = new Client();
        client1.send("Hello from 2nd client\r\n");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Assertions.fail("1st client unable to send message to server. " + e);
    }
}
```